# Stable Convergence in Distribution - Martingale CLT problem (Lemma 3.1 in Hall and Heyde)

Tags: probability, statistics, measure-theory, probability-theory

I'm studying Hall and Heyde's (1980) book on martingale limit theory. In their Lemma 3.1, they seem to use the identity

\begin{equation}
\mathrm{E}\left({\exp{(itZ)}\mathbb{1}_A}\right) = \mathrm{E}\left(\varphi_{Z}(t)\mathbb{1}_A\right) 
\end{equation}
where $/$ is a random variable, $\varphi_{Z}$ is the characteristic function of this random variable, and $\mathbb{1}_A$ is the indicator of an arbitrary measurable set $A$. Why is that "ok"? It's clear for $A=\Omega$ (i.e., the whole space), but for arbitrary $A$? many thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: This identity holds for every $t$ if and only if $Z$ and $A$ are independent. Note that the RHS is $\varphi_Z(t)P(A)$.

Comment: @Did: thanks for your comment!

Answer (score 0):

Fix a real number $s$ and approximate poitwise the bounded function $\exp(isZ)$ by linear combinations of characteristic functions. Assuming the displayed equality true, we would get by an application of dominated convergence theorem that for each $s$ and $t$, 
$$\varphi_Z(s+t)=\varphi_Z(t)\varphi_Z(s),$$
which is not necessarily the case.

It seems it's not what Hall and Heyde use in their Lemma 3.1. Indeed, by theorem 3.1., in order to prove that $S_{n,k_n}\to Z$ stably, it's sufficient to prove that 
$$\forall F\in\mathcal F,\forall t\in\mathbb R,\quad \lim_{n\to\infty}\mathbb E[\exp(it S_{n,k_n})\chi_F]=\mathbb E[\exp(itZ)\chi_F].$$

Comment: hi Davide - thanks for helping me again (it's always good to talk to experts). I was puzzled by that too - since you seem to have a copy of the book at hand, my problem is with display (3.15) on p. 57 - I don't understand why it is sufficient to show this convergence result to establish the claim of the theorem. maybe I'm overlooking (or not understanding) something - and maybe I have phrased the question in the wrong way. thanks again for your help!

Comment: exactly, that's what I thought too. so is (3.15) an "error"? the thing is, the same "sufficient condition" (3.15) is used in several other papers throughout the literature as well (and also in recent ones, e.g., 2010). how would you rectify (3.15), or modify the proof to make it work? thanks!

Comment: maybe I'm confused?

Comment: my question is: does $\mathrm{E}(\exp{(itZ)\chi_A})= \mathrm{E}(\exp{(-1/2 t^2 \eta^2)\chi_A})$ hold?